# Magento 2 render mobile menu items

Tags: magento2, xml, frontend, mobile

Is it possible in M2 to change mobile menu item order?
[image]

I tried looking and couldn't find. I wanna put settings in the back and put menu item in the front using xml.
Basically tried this line
`<move element="store.links" destination="navigation.sections" after="store.settings" />`
and it won't work.

Comment: By default settings are not available in menu theme, and you want to change sort order of menu like, 1.Menu 2. Account 3. Settings

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Example how to use flexbox order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>...</header>
<div id='main'>
   <article>Article</article>
   <nav>Nav</nav>
   <aside>Aside</aside>
</div>
```

css:

```
#main { display: flex;  text-align:center; }
#main > article { flex:1;        order: 2; }
#main > nav     { width: 200px;  order: 1; }
#main > aside   { width: 200px;  order: 3; }
```

Result will be

Nav | Article | Aside

Comment: I am searching a way to change order using xml

Comment: This won't change the order for screen readers or search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code right after `<?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $block->getGroupChildNames($group, 'getChildHtml')):?>` in the sections template `Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml`

```
$detailedInfoGroup = array_filter($block->getChildNames(), function($childName) use($detailedInfoGroup) {
    return in_array($childName, $detailedInfoGroup);
});
```

After adding this, you can change the order as you normally would with XML using `before=""` / `after=""`